# Rails 3.2 - building an app with complex UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface

I'm learning Rails and I'm willing to start developing a web app with it.
I had a previous web development skills and I'd like to know whether it is mandatory to use the JS helpers or if I can develop the UI (with my js framework of choice) separately and host it in /public and let rails only process server side stuff.
I know that this is possible from a pure technical point of view, but is it a good practice when developing rails apps ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a perfectly fine thing to do, though instead of throwing everything in /public perhaps consider /vendor/assets (just from an organisation point of view, using /public is ok).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you point me to some online documentation to better make use of /vendor/assets